# use functions exported in dll

Tags: c, dll

While creating a dll using MSVC(Microsoft Visual C++), one should explicitly export the names that are supposed to be used by others.

Should I explicitly import names that I used in my files?

Example:

```
/*Math.c  will be compiled to a dll*/
__declspec(dllexport) double Sub( double a, double b )
{
    return a - b;
}
```

and compile Math.c to a dll

```
cl /LDd Math.c
```

this generates 4 files Math.dll Math.obj Math.lib Math.exp

I want to use Sub() in my programs and Should I IMPORT Sub like this or not??

```
/*TestMath.c*/
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllimport) double Sub( double a, double b );
//or can I just ignore the __declspec(dllimport) ? 
//I can compile TestMath.c to TestMath.exe without it in Win7 MSVC 2010
//but some books mentioned that you should EXPLICT IMPORT this name like above
int main()
{
    double result = Sub ( 3.0, 2.0 );
    printf( "Result = %f\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

and I compile it with Math.lib to TestMath.exe as:

```
cl /c TestMath.c //TestMath.c->TestMath.obj
link TestMath.obj Math.lib // TestMath.obj->TestMath.exe
```

__decclspec(dllexport) or some .def files to explicit declare export name is necessary, TestMath.exe will run error if there is no export declaration.

And My Question is:
Is IMPORT declaration necessary? Some books say yes, but without it, I can run my demo correctly.

Comment: have you verified your demos doesn't have an export entry with something like PEExplorer or Dependency walker, etc?

Comment: You're implicitly importing by using the function with your demo  prototyped as `__declspec(dllimport)` and linking against the Math.lib import *library* generated as part of the output of your DLL. The loader will properly locate (or try to) your DLL when loading your demo. I.e Your doing it right (except I would have a single header with a single prototype conditionally using export or import declspec depending on whether it is being used to build the DLL or used by a consumer of the library (your demo)).

Comment: @WhozCraig which means explicit import declaration is not necessary as long as I link against the right .lib files?

Comment: @zoujyjs correct. It will stub the entry into the import table, and the loader will seek out the .dll file for you at load-time of your exe.

Comment: @VahidFarahmand Do you mean the TestMath.exe or Math.dll? Math.dll has Export Table that can be seen using dumpbin(like PEEXplorer I guess...): ordinal hint RVA nam 1 0 00001000 Add 2 1 00001020 Mul 3 2 00001010 Sub